# 2 users using same device and same app but different login id -do they have different gcm registration id?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have created table with user_id(unique sno based on email-id) and GCM_id of each user .There are 2 questions I have namely,

1. Can 2 users with different email_id login from the same device and receive gcm w.r.t that user?
2. How do I create and maintain columns in my database.Basically what are the columns I need for getting gcm working if user has installed app on different devices(Mobile,tab-Android) but same email_id ?

I was referring to Android Hive link but someone said that its gcm(2012) and is deprecated.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Summary:
What are the steps I need to take to make latest GCM work properly on multiple devices?
Thanks.
I really appreciate any help .Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the regId depends on the google account on the device, not the email used to login to ur app, so i think both users will get notifications as 1 user, and thats not what u want

Comment: So how can I separate the users from their login id like gmail on multiple devices ?

Comment: you might manipulate the PAY_LOAD, to have the user's email as part of the data, so you display or process notifications with email address equals to current user logged in... maybe?!

Comment: @Yazan How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your app on a given device will have one registration ID. You want to associate that registration ID with the user ID of the current logged in user. So, when a user logs in, you should send to your server the user ID + registration ID and store them in your table. When a user logs out, you should send the user ID to your server and clear the registration ID for that user in your DB.

Now, if you want to support multiple devices for the same user, you'll need to tables. One table for user IDs (in which user ID is unique, and is probably the primary key), and another table for the association of user IDs to registration IDs (in which each user may be associated to multiple registration IDs). Again, you create the user ID - registration ID association during login and delete the association during logout.

Comment: I was thing of the same structure with 2 columns device_id and reg_id and it will have series of device/regid pair and hence it will send to all device ids associated with regid.What do you think? Also if he does not log out .How can I still clear regid.My app does not have logout ? Any alternative?

Comment: @jason If you don't have logout, you can implicitly logout the previous user when a new user logs in. When the new user logs in, you set the reg ID for the new user and clear it for any other user which was previously associated with this ID. Of course, this would be a more expensive DB operation, since you have to search your entire table for that reg ID. It's better to have a logout operation (actually, that can still be implicit - if your device knows the previous logged in user, pass the old user with the new user in the login operation).

Comment: Simple and Understandable Thanks :)

Comment: what happens when I do "clear data", will it still generate the same regID?